# Python + sqlite program, Trying to take data from table and put it into a variable

Tags: python, sqlite

---

Im pretty new to using both python and SQLite3 and im trying to make a basic user authentication system and I need to take the username and password info and put it into a variable to make the system work, any suggestions on how I can do this or if there are any better ways to go about doing this?

This is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

#customers
def customercreate():
    conn = sql.connect('customers1.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers1
        (sipID text PRIMARY KEY,
        firstname text,
        lastname text,
        phone varchar(20),
        town text(30),
        customeruser text,
        customerpass text(25) )""")

    if choice == '1' or choice == 'one':
        sipID = input("Please enter your sipID number")
        firstname = input("Please enter your first name")
        lastname = input("Please enter your last name")
        phone = input("Please enter your phone number")
        town = input("Please enter your town/city of residence")
        customeruser = input("Please create a username for your account")
        customerpass = input("Please create a password for your account")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO customers1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
        (sipID, firstname, lastname, phone, town, customeruser, customerpass))
    print("\033[32mInformation Entered Successfully\033[0m")
       
    conn.commit()
    
choice = input("Press 1 to sign in as a customer, press 2 to create a customer account")

if choice != '1':
    customercreate()
elif choice == '1':
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your paassword")
    

f"SELECT customeruser from customers1 WHERE customeruser ='{username}' AND customerpass = '{password}'";
```

The code works perfectly fine up until I need to actually authenticate the user so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We will not solve your homework. Code for user authentification is missing.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to implement a function like this:

```
def sign_in(username, password):
    conn = sql.connect('customers1.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('SELECT customeruser from customers1 WHERE (customeruser = ? AND customerpass = ?)', (username, password))
    user = cur.fetchall()
    if not user:
        user = False
    else:
        user = user[0][0]
    return user
```